# Grape vine why is it drying up

Tags: diagnosis, soil-amendment, drainage, grape-vine, optimal-conditions

So I planted this grapevine in spring. It started from a little twig was growing beautifully health all green and vibrant but like five weeks ago started seeing leafs drying up see below pix(the leafs that are blotchy, only looks better in pix but it's really yellower). I don't see any pest or signs that could cause a stress. Please let me know what could do this  can this be the normal process of fall or did the roots reach the clay soil and is being affected somehow?
If that's the case should I replant it on higher level with even more amended soil?
Can this be done safely once it goes dormant?

Im located in south Jersey Soil is clay but was amended with leafcompost, micronutrients stuff and topped with 4" woodchips. Only watered it when planted and monitored the moister level before watering again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess your right.  I did see some trees start to drop their leafs. Guess I'm in denial that summers over 

Answer (score 1):

It could just be the end of growing season. Here in zone 8 ( East TX) the sweet gums are dropping leaves and the sour gums have many red leaves ; our temperatures are typically in the 80's and it has not been dry.